# Mockito catch callback message

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a mock callback object

```
Callback callback = mock(Callback.class);
```

This object has two methods, `done()` and `failed(String msg)`.

I do a

```
verify(callback).done();
```

to see that `done()` was called, but when things dont turn up so well and `failed(String msg)` is called instead, how can i print `msg`?

Comment: Can you post your CallBack and test Code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the `msg` when verifying that `failed()` is called, for example in the test class you can define:

```
@Mock private Callback mockCallback;
@Captor private ArgumentCaptor<String> stringCaptor;
```

and in the test itself:

```
verify(mockCallback).falied(stringCaptor.capture());

final List<String> capturedMessages = stringCaptor.getAllValues();
final String actualMsg = capturedMessages.get(0);
final String expectedMsg = "foo";

assertEquals(expectedMsg, actualMsg);
```

Note: the `@Captor` annotation was introduced in mockito v1.8.3. If you are using a version prior to this, there is an example of the previous syntax in the linked API above.

Comment: Link is no more.